# Can you only communicate once with a subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

[`communicate`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)'s documentation says:

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.

What do you do if you need to send input to a process more than once ? For example, I spawn a process, send it some data, the process does something with that, returns some output, and then I have to send input again? How do I handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `subprocess` for this, you'll enter a world of pain to do with buffering.

I recommend [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) for this purpose - it works very well.  Unfortunately it doesn't work under windows at the moment, though I did hear about a port (which I can't find any more).

Answer (score 3):

Then you can't use `.communicate()`. You can either poll the streams, use `select` or some other way that allows you to listen to FD changes (both gtk and Qt have tools for that, for example).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Doug Hellman's Python Module of the Week writeup about subprocess](http://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/index.html#module-subprocess). Search down until you see "repeater.py".

There you will find an example of how to send and receive input/output to a process.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a module I wrote. Make sure to use that -u argument to avoid buffering problems:

```
import os
import pickle
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
import struct
import builtins
def call_thru_stream(stream,funcname,*args,**kwargs):
    """Used for calling a function through a stream and no return value is required. It is assumed
    the receiving program is in the state where it is expecting a function."""
    transmit_object(stream,(funcname,args,kwargs))


def function_thru_stream(in_stream,out_stream,funcname,*args,**kwargs):
    """Used for calling a function through a stream where a return value is required. It is assumed
    the receiving program is in the state where it is expecting a function."""
    transmit_object(in_stream,(funcname,args,kwargs))
    return receive_object(out_stream)

#--------------------- Object layer ------------------------------------------------------------

def transmit_object(stream,obj):
    """Transmits an object through a binary stream"""
    data=pickle.dumps(obj,2)#Uses pickle version 2 for compatibility with 2x
    transmit_atom(stream,data)


def receive_object(stream):
    """Receive an object through a binary stream"""
    atom=receive_atom(stream)
    return pickle.loads(atom)

#--------------------- Atom layer --------------------------------------------------------------
def transmit_atom(stream, atom_bytes):
    """Used for transmitting a some bytes which should be treated as an atom through
    a stream. An integer indicating the size of the atom is appended to the start."""
    header=struct.pack("=L",len(atom_bytes))
    stream.write(header)
    stream.write(atom_bytes)
    stream.flush()


def receive_atom(stream):
    """Read an atom from a binary stream and return the bytes."""
    input_len=stream.read(4)
    l=struct.unpack("=L",input_len)[0]
    return stream.read(l)
```